# Replacing array macro with regex

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I wanted to remove a macro in one of the projects I’ve been working on, and it will required a script to do it as there’s 800+ occurrences in the c/cpp source. Note that although this macro appears in cpp files, the declarations and types are all plain c.

The macro in question looks like this:

```
#define ARRAY(data_type, size, array_name) data_type array_name[size]
```

When it’s used in source, it looks like this:

```
#define BAR_LEN 2

struct Foo_t
{
   uint16_t example;
   ARRAY(uint8_t, BAR_LEN, Bar);  //<-- This line
   uint8_t target;
};
```

Now, I can list all the source files

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/.*\.(h|c|cpp)' -print0
```

And potentially pipe them into xargs for use with another utility like awk or sed. The problem is, I’m not sure which direction to take. Using the example above, my goal is to convert:

```
struct Foo_t
{
   uint16_t example;
   ARRAY(uint8_t, BAR_LEN, Bar); //<-- This line
   uint8_t target;
};
```

To

```
struct Foo_t
{
   uint16_t example;
   uint8_t Bar[BAR_LEN];  //<-- This line
   uint8_t target;
};
```

However, there’s many declarations that use that macro, which pass different parameters for each call. Also, the macro usage has formatting variations in terms of spacing. I'm a bit stumped at the moment, any direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:**

For testing purposes, I created a Test.txt file to test the commands against, all it contains is the following 4 lines:

```
ARRAY( uint8_t, 16, Bar1);
ARRAY(uint8_t,4,Bar2);
ARRAY(uint8_t, 18,Bar3);
ARRAY(uint8_t,2, Bar4);
```

The actual usage can be found in the link below:

https://onlinegdb.com/Skpstxn1N

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add the (Perl) code you've already written? Most likely, you're better served by using `gcc` in preprocessor mode to expand your macros, but if you only (and exactly) want to expand _this_ macro, a oneliner like `perl -pie 's/\bARRAY\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*\)/$1 $3[$2]/g' *.c` might do it already, provided the macro invocation is always on a single line and the types itself are simple identifiers.

Comment: Things quickly become complicated if you have stuff like `ARRAY(Ctype<foo,bar>,C_LEN,cname)` (notice the happy <comma> sitting between `foo` and `bar`)

Comment: ... but hopefully, your C code is simple and/or you can manually edit the remaining cases. A solution that expands 80% of the `ARRAY` macro is still better than editing those 640 lines yourself...

Comment: Thanks @Corion I created a quick test file to experiment with this command. It contains(Test.txt):

`ARRAY( uint8_t, BAR_LEN, Bar1);`    
`ARRAY(uint8_t,BAR_LEN,Bar2);`  
`ARRAY(uint8_t, BAR_LEN,Bar3);`  
`ARRAY(uint8_t,BAR_LEN, Bar4);`  

When I ran the following command:

`perl -i -pe 's/\bARRAY\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*\)/$1 $3[$2]/g' Test.txt`

The result is:

`uint8_t ;`
`uint8_t ;`
`uint8_t ;`
`uint8_t ;`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add the test file. Most likely you need `perl -i -pe 's/\bARRAY\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*\)/$1 $3\[$2\]/g' Test.txt` or maybe you need to double the backslashes for your shell or somehing like that. If you post the example file in your question, I can try things myself.

Comment: Awesome @Corion, I updated my question. Instead of hosting the file somewhere I just pasted its contents as it was only a few lines of text. I also added a quick link just to show an example of the c declarations.

Comment: Ah - I had the command line switches a bit mixed up. The following works for me (under `bash`): `perl -pi -e 's/\bARRAY\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*\)/$1 $3\[$2\]/g'`

Comment: Thank you @Corion, your solution worked perfectly. If you want, you can convert your comment to an answer so I can accept your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you're better served by using gcc in preprocessor mode to expand your macros, but if you only (and exactly) want to expand this macro, the following oneliner might do it already, provided the macro invocation is always on a single line and the types itself are simple identifiers as in your example.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\bARRAY\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*\)/$1 $3\[$2\]/g' *.c
```

This outputs for your test data:

```
uint8_t Bar1[16];
uint8_t Bar2[4];
uint8_t Bar3[18];
uint8_t Bar4[2];
```

Another approach would be to run `gcc -E`, but that will expand all `#include`s as well.